# Django specifying password reset email subject

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have setup my django application to use the built in auth.views to reset password. The problem is that this is what the message looks like:

```
Subject: Password reset on 127.0.0.1:8001

You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at 127.0.0.1:8001.

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:

http://127.0.0.1:8001/accounts/reset/MQ/4j3-d83f7cdb7f0203afe85e/

Your username, in case you've forgotten: myuser

Thanks for using our site!

The 127.0.0.1:8001 team
```

It seems like it's pulling localhost from the gunicorn deployment. I have it set up so that nginx routes the domain @port 80 to localhost at port 8001. How do I go about changing this to have "http://mydomain/accounts/reset...." instead?

Seems like people are downvoting this because it isn't specific enough. Here's what I have set up:

```
url(r'^resetpassword/passwordsent/$', password_reset_done, {'template_name': 'password_recovery/recover_password_sent.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),
url(r'^resetpassword/$', password_reset, {'template_name': 'password_recovery/recover_password.html'}, name='password_reset'),
```

These urls are pulling from `django.contrib.auth.views`. And it seems like {{ domain }} variable is what they're using to construct the email. The problem is, it's pulling localhost as my domain since the gunicorn daemon is binding it to localhost at port 8001. How would I go about modifying it so that I get the actual domain, is there a variable in settings.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's getting the site name from the `Site` object, or if it's not available then from `request.META`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset

So configuring a Site object could fix this for you.

Comment: Does this mean that I have to extend the password reset view?

Comment: No, try just adding a Site object (using the admin or shell) and give it the name you'd like to use. Probably relevant: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/

Comment: Yup, seems like that did the trick! Thank you so much. Didn't know this existed!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have just go to admin and configure your site to http://mydomain, because domain variable in the reset template is taken from there:

in view:

```
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    site_name = current_site.name
    domain = current_site.domain
```

in template:

```
{% autoescape off %}{% load usertools %}Hi {{user|display_name}},

You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for your user account at {{domain}}.

Your username: {{user.get_username}}

Please go to the following page and choose a new password:

{{protocol}}://{{domain}}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}

If clicking isn't working for you, simply paste the URL into your favorite web browser.

See you soon!{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: I'm currently using the buil tin auth view. Does this mean I have to recreate the view?